# Upload Multiple Image in React using axios

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, axios

I have here a problem with multiple images. My problem is that I want to upload multiples image through an API. The API can't handle it through one request. That's why I wanted to upload images one by one and call the API one by one. How do i do it?

```
export const saveImages =
  ({ images = [], oldImages, isNew }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.REQUEST,
      });

      let responses;

      if (images?.length) {
        let formData = new FormData();

        const requests = images.map(({ imageFileName, imageFile }) => {
          formData.append(imageFileName, imageFile);
          formData.append("isNewProduct", isNew);
          
          return axios.post(
            `${URL}/saveImages`,
            formData
          );
        });

        responses = await Promise.all(requests);
      }

      dispatch({
        type: constants.SUCCESS,
        payload: [...(oldImages || []), ...response?.data],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.FAILURE,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: It looks like it's not about React but `axios` library

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate the `images` array and make individual network requests? What is the point of having a `"/bulk-upload-image"` endpoint if you can't bulk upload to it? Do you have a different endpoint to use for single individual uploads? What have you tried already?

Comment: @DrewReese. Yes I want to iterate images and make individual api request. This is what I have tried so far. My problem is I want to make multiple request but have to wait for others to finish and dispatch success as one.

Comment: Does `response = await axios.post(\`${URL}/bulk-upload-image\`, formData);` not process them all at once and give you success? If you really need to split them up into individual requests then map the images to an array of Promises (axios.post) and `await Promise.all(....)` them. When all mapped promises resolve then `Promise.all` resolves.

Comment: @DrewReese. I don't want to process them in one request. I'm experimenting on multiple request if possible. Can you help me answer this question by mapping them the images and using Promise.all? Thank you Drew

Comment: What is your "solo image" request URL and body, same? Request headers? etc...? Does that matter for this demonstration?

Comment: @DrewReese. Just use the `${URL}/upload-images`

Comment: @DrewReese. yes just use the same body etc... for this demo. I'm doing the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to split them up into individual requests then map the images to an array of Promises (axios.post) and `await Promise.all(....)` them. When all mapped promises resolve then `Promise.all` resolves.

```
export const uploadMultipleImages = ({ images }) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: constants.REQUEST });

    // Map images to array of axios.post Promises
    const requests = images.map(({ imageFileName, imageFile })=> {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(imageFileName, imageFile);
      return axios.post(`${URL}/upload-image`, formData);
    });

    // await all promises to resolve, responses is an array of all
    // resolved Promise values, i.e. whatever the POST requests
    // return
    const responses = await Promise.all(requests);

    dispatch({
      type: constants.SUCCESS,
      payload: responses,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: constants.FAILURE });
  }
};
```

If I recall correctly on previous questions sometimes the images would have missing properties, so if this is still the case then you may want to use a `.filter` function before mapping to POST requests.

Comment: @Joseph I think it should probably be `payload: [...(oldImages || []), ...responses],` but otherwise, yeah, seems alright. May want to just give `responses` an initial value, i.e. `let responses = []`, this way if no POST requests are made then you only spread an empty array.

Comment: @Joseph Oh, you are using only a single `formData` object and keep appending into it. Notice in my answer a new `formData` is created for each request. It's *inside* the map callback.

Comment: @Joseph The `await` is on the `Promise.all` since it returns a Promise.

Comment: @Joseph In the [request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) there appears to be an `onUploadProgress` property. I've never done any sort of progress processing so this is about as far as I can get you currently.

Comment: Hi again Drew. regarding this one. can we do the request one by one. Like if we finish the first one, it will proceed to the next one and so on. Not doing request simultaneously?

Comment: @Joseph Yup. I started looking into it last night but got pulled away. You basically just need an asynchronous for-loop. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-multiple-image-in-react-using-axios-7pqpl